# Why is Mars favored over Venus?

Tags: mars, future-missions, venus, terraforming

There's been a lot of talk in the last years about a trip to Mars (with SpaceX having the most serious intentions). I can understand that it has a less harsh environment and it will be easier to land and take off from the surface due to lower gravity, but Venus has lots of advantages too!

My comparison:

*Gravity*
Lower on Mars - easier landing and take-off, lower energy consumption for everyday operations.
On Venus almost same as on Earth - potentially MUCH healthier for humans. This single feature could outweigh all the other advantages on Mars in long term.

*Environment (atmospheric conditions)*
Milder on Mars - easier to build reliable housing and suits for outdoor activities.
Harsher on Venus - because of temperatures and acids in atmosphere probably classic suits won't be enough. Will probably need to design mecha-like, exoskeletal-assisted vehicles https://static.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/51ce6099e4b0d911b4489b79/51ce6197e4b0d911b4499697/1303346867025/1000w/Heavy_Mech.jpg.
But nothing an engineer couldn't do these days.

*Sustainable energy*
Much less energy from the Sun on Mars (because farther from the Sun).
A hell lot of direct solar energy on Venus, plus the environment is so hot that there is no need to use solar panels. Just put out the turbines and they will run on the hot Venusian air.

*Terraforming*
Mars probably much easier to terraform than Venus (I mean mainly the atmosphere). But in both cases this procedure is so long-term it doesn't really matter for us in the near future.

*Natural resources*
Probably different amount of different resources but still same overall potential on both planets.

*Further space exploration*
A bit easier from Mars because closer to other planets (and the outer bounds of the solar system).

Comment: This is way too broad. Where to start? There's also been proposals to colonize Venusian atmosphere in aerostats, should we include that too? Please see if you could [edit] your question to substantially narrow its scope down and see our [Ask] for some suggestions how to write good questions. Also, what has tag [tag:future-missions] got to do with your question? I don't see it specifically identifying any, and none to Venus. Thanks!

Comment: *Just put out the turbines and they will run on the hot Venusian air.* -- No, they won't. To run turbines, you need a *difference* in temperature. If the entire ambient environment is equally hot, the turbines won't turn. As for solar energy, most of it is blocked by Venus's atmosphere; I haven't done the numbers, but I suspect solar panels will work *better* on Mars than on the surface of Venus (aside from the fact that on Mars the components won't melt).

Comment: [Landis has some ideas about Venus](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/why-we-should-build-cloud-cities-on-venus): Go to the 50-60 Km altitude range, where it is almost Gaia-like. (Ooops, just adding up to @TidalWave indeed)

Comment: Please note that SpaceX mentions Mars often, because it is the hype. SpaceX also stresses their "multi-planet" target; and it is a business. If Venus becomes viable financially, SpaceX will probably jump on it. Being closer can make it a good trial to go to Mars afterwards.

Comment: I think this question would work if it was phrased something like "Why is Mars favored over Venus for colonization" (as it basically is in the question title), and drop all the speculative/wrong stuff from the question. Although the answer might be obvious to a knowledgeable person, it's still not a bad question. Essentially the question is: Why is it much easier to colonize a cold planet with a thin atmosphere, than a hot one with a thick atmosphere?

Comment: Well, I admit I am not the knowledgeable person and I don't see why the question should be downvoted. It's not broad. I'm asking for specific and practical comparison of all pros and cons which lead people to decide to choose Mars (for colonization or just single manned missions).

Comment: The fundamental problem with trying to go to Venus is trying to stay cool enough to survive.  Unlike cold place where all you need is a heat source, Venus is a ***hot*** place - and I'm not aware of any "cool sources" you could carry in to deal with the problem.  If you can do that - carry ***coldness*** with you, then all of the other Venus problems theoretically become less of an issue.

Answer (score 5):

> Will probably need to design mecha-like, exoskeletal-assisted vehicles https://static.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/51ce6099e4b0d911b4489b79/51ce6197e4b0d911b4499697/1303346867025/1000w/Heavy_Mech.jpg. But nothing an engineer couldn't do these days.

Please show me these massive self-contained mechanical suits that are somehow easy to build?

Venus is hot - about 467°C.  How do you plan to live in an environment that's considerably hotter than molten lead?

Venus's atmosphere is under extreme pressure - about 93 times that of Earths atmosphere.  For comparison the world record scuba dive is about a third of that.  This is caused by less than 1 atmosphere of differance:

and even nuclear attack submarines would collapse at around [74 atmospheres.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_depth_ratings)

Venus faces constant rain made of sulfuric acid.... enough said.

I suggest taking a look at how much submarines cost, how little comfort they can afford, and then consider that they aren't in an oven, aren't exposed to acid and have ready access to water, air, cooling and supplies!

Comment: Atmo density on Venus is ca.100x of atmo density on Earth. Water density on Earth is 1000x denser than the air on Earth. We can survive in water (with scuba gear of course) so I'd assume we could survive the pressure on Venus too. The real problems would be temperature and acids. But there are metals which remain in solid state in much higher temperatures and can survive sulfuric acid. So is it really an obstacle?
http://www.onlinemetals.com/meltpt.cfm

Comment: I mean, it is definitely a greater obstacle compared to Mars but how much greater? Is there any way to estimate it? And am I wrong that the Earth-like gravity on Venus could outweigh the obstacles?

Comment: @ValCool Please see Wiki for [pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure) and [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density). They are NOT one and the same thing.

Comment: Do you have a citation for your claim that we have metals that are durable against hot sulfuric acid?

Comment: I'm absolutely not an expert but it seems some materials could endure in such conditions
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/metal-corrosion-resistance-d_491.html

Comment: @ValCool as I note in my answer the pressures experiences on Venus's surface are far higher than the pressures any scuba diver has survived.  That world record isn't there because they felt like stopping early.  I'm sure there are materials who survive in tougher conditions... and as long as we simply send down a blob of said material then it's really not that hard at all.  Human's aren't made of said material unfortunately.

Comment: @Val, as a first indication of the difference in difficulty, consider the lifespan of probes we've sent so far. Venus: 1.5 hours, Mars: 10 years and counting.

Comment: OK, Hobbes, that sounds like some concrete argument. That's what I was hoping for. If you post some more of such specific, practical comparison, I'll be more than happy to mark it as the answer

Comment: @NPSF3000, I didn't say the mecha-suits are easy to build. What I meant is they will definitely be possible in the near future. Eg. a combination of this
http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/462529771_640.jpg
and this
http://anime.mx/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/KURATAS_03.jpg
Or this (this is already working!):
http://anthrobotic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/MANTIS.BADASS.DAMN_.RIGHT_-e1366877389206.png

Comment: @ValCool You didn't exactly say it would be easy, but your entire argument is that Venus is a better exploration and colonization target than Mars. The surface of Venus is way out of bounds for us. The solar system is teeming with easier targets. The [upper atmosphere](http://www.cnn.com/2014/12/23/tech/innovation/tomorrow-transformed-venus-blimp-city) of Venus, on the other hand, may be a possibility soon.

Comment: @ValCool I think you drastically overestimate the capabilities of those 'suits'... we have just about grasped the basic ability of walking (with numerous multiple legs, none of this two legged nonsense).  And that's in perfect scenarios - not this molten, pressurised hell.  This is caused by less than 1 atmosphere of difference:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz95_VvTxZM